# WINS tool missing from netsh

Tags: windows-xp, wins, netsh

I run up 'netsh' on my Windows XP box, and type

> help

One of the options is wins (to change to the 'netsh wins' context).

From the netsh context I can type "wins" and I get into the wins context just fine.

Problem is, from another machine on the same domain, I can list netsh options, but wins is missing.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Windows 2003 Administration Tools Pack installs the WINS component into netsh.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

No idea, why this Windows XP is missing the WINS tool. Windows Vista's netsh doesn't include it, but it should be available on Windows XP.

As a workaround you could use Microsoft's

[**NBLookup.exe command-line tool**](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;830578)

> NBLookup is a command line diagnostic
>   tool that uses the User Datagram
>   Protocol (UDP) to send NetBIOS name
>   queries to Microsoft Windows Internet
>   Naming Service (WINS) servers.
>   NBLookup requires TCP/IP version 4 to
>   run. WINS servers accept name
>   resolution requests on UDP port 137.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the link. It perfectly solves my problem - and is better than using netsh. I've since figured out the answer to my original question though, so I'll put that down as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

What service pack of XP are you running?

I just fired up an XP SP1 vm, had a look at the command list and the winsock ("wins") is missing.
So that machine looks like it needs to be upgraded to SP2 at least.

Comment: wins != winsock